# File Reader is slow and not set state on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, filereader

When converting a. pdf file to Base64, I need to be filled in my state, but for some reason my conversion is slower than my setstate, which when being seted is always empty.

My code

```
async transformBase64(inputFile) {    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(inputFile)
      if (fileReader.result != undefined){
        resolve(this.setState({ Base64: fileReader.result }), () => {});                
      }else{
        reject("Err")
      }            
    });
  }
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: is `fileReader.readAsDataURL(inputFile)` supposed to be sync or async?

Comment: @bsapaka is async

Comment: so shoudn't it be  `await fileReader.readAsDataURL(inputFile)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not setting up an `onload` callback for your `fileReader`. This is needed to correctly signal back to your application that file data has loaded and is ready, seeing that the `FileReader` API is asynchronous.

Consider apply the following changes to your code to resolve your problem:

```
async transformBase64(inputFile) {    

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      // If error occurs, reject the promise
      fileReader.onerror = () => {
          reject("Err")
      }

      // Define an onload handler that's called when file loaded
      fileReader.onload = () => {

        // File data loaded, so proceed to call setState
        if (fileReader.result != undefined){
          resolve(this.setState({ 
             Base64: fileReader.result 
          }), () => {});                
        }else{
          reject("Err")
        }  
      }

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(inputFile)

    });
  }
```